# How to pop the first element in a java stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I just want to get the first element of a java stream, remove it and get on with my life. How can I do this without making it overly complicated (like with `forEach`, `casting` or `filter`)?

Comment: A `Stream` is not an `Iterator`. (But it does have a `findFirst` method.)

Comment: There is `findFirst()` but this is a short-circuiting terminal operation. You won't be able to process the Stream after calling it.

Comment: if you want to use the stream excluding the first element you can also `stream.skip(1).getOnWithYourLife();`

Comment: Streams do not remove or modify the input data. The concept of stream (or functional programming) is that every stream operation results in a new (immutable) dataset (output is a function of input). So whatever you do, you'll never modify the stream, you make a new one. Therefore, the closest to popping an element is stream filtering (e.g. skipping the the first).

Comment: As assylias said, skipping the first element is as easy as calling `skip(1)`. If you want to retrieve that value, you have to convert the `Stream` into an `Iterator`, or better `Spliterator`, get the first element from it and create a new `Stream` out of it.

Comment: you can do it like this : `persons.stream().findFirst().ifPresent(person -> persons.remove(person))`;